# Python - Unable to rotate userAgent dynamically in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, user-agent

I am overriding default implemenation of scrapy modules **HttpProxyMiddleware** and **UserAgentMiddleware**, and my own implementation of scrapy rotates user-agent and IP address, which picks the values randomly from the list provided. IP is changing for every request but not user-agent. I am unable to figureout the reason.

Here is my implementation of classes

**RotateUserAgentMiddleware**

```
    class RotateUserAgentMiddleware(UserAgentMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, user_agent=''):
        self.user_agent = user_agent

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        ua = random.choice(self.user_agent_list)
        if ua:
            request.headers.setdefault('User-Agent', ua)
            # Add desired logging message here.
            spider.log(
                u'User-Agent: {} {}'.format(request.headers.get('User-Agent'), request)
                      )
```

**ProxyMiddleware**

```
class ProxyMiddleware(HttpProxyMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, proxy_ip=''):
        self.proxy_ip = proxy_ip

    def process_request(self,request,spider):
        ip = random.choice(self.proxy_list)
        if ip:

            request.meta['proxy'] = ip
            print(request.meta)
        return request
```

Changes made in **Downloader_Middleware** in ***settings.py*** are;

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': None,
    'IpRotation.ProxyMiddleware.ProxyMiddleware': 800,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware' : None,
    'IpRotation.RotateUserAgentMiddleware.RotateUserAgentMiddleware':790
}
```

Printing the **Ip** and **user-agent** values on my console for **each request**:

```
    2015-10-09 15:51:46 [dmoz] DEBUG: User-Agent: Scrapy/1.0.3 (+http://scrapy.org) <GET http://www.imdb.com/chart/top>
{'download_timeout': 180.0, 'proxy': '198.*.*.*:80'}
2015-10-09 15:51:46 [dmoz] DEBUG: User-Agent: Scrapy/1.0.3 (+http://scrapy.org) <GET http://www.imdb.com/chart/top>
{'download_timeout': 180.0, 'proxy': '195.*.*.*:3120'}
2015-10-09 15:51:46 [dmoz] DEBUG: User-Agent: Scrapy/1.0.3 (+http://scrapy.org) <GET http://www.imdb.com/chart/top>
{'download_timeout': 180.0, 'proxy': '94.*.*.*:3128'}
2015-10-09 15:51:47 [dmoz] DEBUG: User-Agent: Scrapy/1.0.3 (+http://scrapy.org) <GET http://www.imdb.com/chart/top>
{'download_timeout': 180.0, 'proxy': '94.*.*.*:3128'}
2015-10-09 15:51:47 [dmoz] DEBUG: User-Agent: Scrapy/1.0.3 (+http://scrapy.org) <GET http://www.imdb.com/chart/top>
{'download_timeout': 180.0, 'proxy': '198.*.*.*:80'}
2015-10-09 15:51:47 [dmoz] DEBUG: User-Agent: Scrapy/1.0.3 (+http://scrapy.org) <GET http://www.imdb.com/chart/top>
{'download_timeout': 180.0, 'proxy': '94.*.*.*:3128'}
2015-10-09 15:51:47 [dmoz] DEBUG: User-Agent: Scrapy/1.0.3 (+http://scrapy.org) <GET http://www.imdb.com/chart/top>
{'download_timeout': 180.0, 'proxy': '94.*.*.*:3128'}
2015-10-09 15:51:47 [dmoz] DEBUG: User-Agent: Scrapy/1.0.3 (+http://scrapy.org) <GET http://www.imdb.com/chart/top>
{'download_timeout': 180.0, 'proxy': '195.*.*.*:3120'}
2015-10-09 15:51:47 [dmoz] DEBUG: User-Agent: Scrapy/1.0.3 (+http://scrapy.org) <GET http://www.imdb.com/chart/top>
{'download_timeout': 180.0, 'proxy': '200.*.*.*:80'}
2015-10-09 15:51:47 [dmoz] DEBUG: User-Agent: Scrapy/1.0.3 (+http://scrapy.org) <GET http://www.imdb.com/chart/top>
{'download_timeout': 180.0, 'proxy': '198.*.*.*:80'}
2015-10-09 15:51:47 [dmoz] DEBUG: User-Agent: Scrapy/1.0.3 (+http://scrapy.org) <GET http://www.imdb.com/chart/top>
{'download_timeout': 180.0, 'proxy': '213.*.*.*:80'}
2015-10-09 15:51:47 [dmoz] DEBUG: User-Agent: Scrapy/1.0.3 (+http://scrapy.org) <GET http://www.imdb.com/chart/top>
{'download_timeout': 180.0, 'proxy': '198.*.*.*:80'}
2015-10-09 15:51:47 [dmoz] DEBUG: User-Agent: Scrapy/1.0.3 (+http://scrapy.org) <GET http://www.imdb.com/chart/top>
{'download_timeout': 180.0, 'proxy': '200.*.*.*:80'}
2015-10-09 15:51:48 [dmoz] DEBUG: User-Agent: Scrapy/1.0.3 (+http://scrapy.org) <GET http://www.imdb.com/chart/top>
{'download_timeout': 180.0, 'proxy': '58.*.*.*:80'}
```

Did not change USER_AGENT in settings.py since I have to assign the value randomly:

```
# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
#USER_AGENT = 'IPProxy (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'
```

In the whole project, the place where I am not clear is assigning the values to the Downloader_Middleware. None says scrapy to ignore the class but what the Integers says? Please someone help me out from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the value of       'IpRotation.RotateUserAgentMiddleware.RotateUserAgentMiddleware' in Downloader_Middleware to les than 400.