# scrapy-user-agents: UnsupportedBrowserType WARNING

Tags: python, scrapy

This post comes from another post [Scrapy encounters DEBUG: Crawled (400)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62668523/12214867).

I'm not sure whether the WARNING is blocking my crawler.

I'm using Python 3.7.7 on macOS 10.13 with Scrapy 2.1.0 and scrapy-user-agents 0.1.1

I've already added DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES and DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,     'scrapy_user_agents.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400, }

DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'}
```

I ran this command in terminal and I got some available Scrapy objects, which means Scrapy and Middleware work well.

```
scrapy shell 'https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/grammar'
```

In the meanwhile, I got some warnings

```
2020-07-01 13:27:48 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedBrowserType] Family: Android
2020-07-01 13:27:49 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None
...
2020-07-01 13:27:49 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: LG Web0S SmartTV, Brand: LG, Model: Web0S SmartTV
...
2020-07-01 13:27:51 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedBrowserType] Family: SMTBot
2020-07-01 13:27:51 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedBrowserType] Family: PhantomJS
...
```

What does the WARNING mean?

If they are not fatal, how do I silence them?

Comment: Where do you get that warning? In general, it would help if you provided a [mcve]. Anyway, check out the code that emits the warning: How does its behaviour change when it encounters an unknown browser? For what does it need the browser at all?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thanks for your reminder. I just updated the OP. Running `scrapy shell 'https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/grammar'` in terminal could reproduce the warnings in question.

Comment: Are you using https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-user-agents/ ? Because it looks like the project is dead.

Comment: @Gallaecio Yes, it is. Is there an alternative to that?

Comment: There’s an even older package suggestion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56082653/trying-to-fake-and-rotating-user-agents#comment98813699_56082653 , but I wonder if that will work. Alterrnatively, you could try and fix the error, and maintain a fork of the middleware.